# javascript stop setTimeout after containing object deleted or overwritten

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I would like to stop a timer after I delete the variable containing the function that ran it.

The following works but requires an extra step:

```js
foo = (function() {
    function doSomething() {
        console.log('I am running ')
        timer1 = setTimeout(doSomething, 2000)
    }
    doSomething()
    console.log('timer is #' + (bob))
    return {
        stopTimer: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer1)
            return true
        }
    }
})()
// 
// let it run a while..
// 
// later, stop it .. this works but is an extra step
foo.stopTimer()
// no more logs .. success
```

That is, it stops the timer.  However the REAL OBJECTIVE is just to do this:

```js
foo = <new code like a new version overwriting the existing one>
-- or less desirably --
foo = null
```

And have the timer(s) stop.  Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible*, but only by using tricks, which I'd highly recommend not doing, because they greatly obfuscate the intent of the code.

By putting `foo` on the global object (or with `with` - please don't), you can make it a getter/setter, where the setter will, when invoked, call the `stopTimer`.

```js
let timer1;
function doSomething() {
    console.log('I am running ')
    timer1 = setTimeout(doSomething, 1000)
}
doSomething();
Object.defineProperty(
  window,
  'foo',
  {
    set(newArg) {
      clearTimeout(timer1);
      // delete this setter
      delete window.foo
      window.foo = newArg;
    },
    configurable: true
  }
);

button.onclick = () => {
  console.log('stopping timer');
  foo = null;
  console.log('new value of window.foo:', foo);
};
```

```html
<button id="button">stop</button>
```

A more sensible approach, if your objective is to not to have to both have a line that calls `foo.stopTimer` and also have a line that creates a new timer (or something) would be to create a method that both stops the timer and creates the new desired one at once, like

```
//               callback                  interval
foo.makeNewTimer(() => console.log('new'), 1000);
```

Comment: k that's cool, but yeah as you implied, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.